# Isomorphic to an affine space

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Given a polynomial $p$ in  $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, 
when is its vanishing set isomorphic to an affine space? 
I think that this only happens if $p$ is linear.

Maybe is easy to prove by contradiction by
intersecting with general hyperplanes, until the polynomial becomes a non-linear polynomial in one variable.

Is this true? Is there any shorter proof?

Comment: What about $p(x) := x^k \in \Bbb C[x]$?

Comment: I am thinking about the irreducible case for sure

Comment: I don't think this is true.  

Exercise 3.1 in Hartshorne says that any conic in $\mathbb{A}^2$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{A}^1$ or $\mathbb{A}^1 - \{ 0 \}$.  You can probably find an example where the first case is true pretty easily.

Comment: In particular i think you can show that $Z(y - x^2) \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ by showing that $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y - x^2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[z]$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

Comment: Polynomial rings have many non-linear automorphisms and a linear equation can be transformed to a non-linear one. So, a more useful question might be, given such a $p$, does there exist an automorphism which transforms it into a linear equation. I believe even this is wrong by an example of Nagata (though am not absolutely certain). The only non-trivial case known is for $n=2$, so called Abhyankar-Moh theorem.